# How to override LaTeX template's string constants

Tags: latex

I'm typesetting my CV using the europecv LaTeX class. I don't actually need to conform to the EU's standardized CV form, but I like the general layout of it. One thing that bothers me about the class is how it sets certain headings, for instance

**Surname(s) / First name(s)**: Smith, John

Where I'd rather have

**Name**: John Smith

I've found that these string constants for English are defined in a file called "ecven.def" thus:

```
\def\ecv@infosectionkey{\ecv@utf{Personal information}}
\def\ecv@namekey{\ecv@utf{Surname(s) / First name(s)}}
\def\ecv@addresskey{\ecv@utf{Address(es)}}
\def\ecv@telkey{\ecv@utf{Telephone(s)}}
\def\ecv@mobilekey{\ecv@utf{Mobile}}
```

I guess I could just edit this file to change them, but that seems like the wrong approach. I tried to do this at the top of my document:

```
\renewcommand{\ecv@namekey}{\ecv@utf{Name}}
```

which gives this error:

```
./eurocv.tex:22: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

And I've tried this:

```
\def\ecv@namekey{\ecv@utf{Name}}
```

which doesn't give an error, but doesn't change the output. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the \makeatletter and \makeatother commands wrapping your changes.

```
\makeatletter
\def\ecv@namekey{\ecv@utf{Name}}
...
\makeatother
```